# List symbolic links and location, pointing to a particular directory

Tags: shell, unix

How to list all symbolic links that are pointing to a particular directory in Solaris?

I used find command on root directory and grep on top of it. This is extremely slow.

please suggest any other alternatives.

Comment: please indicate which `find` you been using

Comment: i am usinf find command in Soalris with -type l option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic links are uni-directional and 'entirely contained' in each link file - there's no separate list of links, or reverse link - you'll have to use find.

I presume you're using `find / -type l` to restrict 'find' to only report files that are symbolic links.

Have you restricted the search to eliminate areas that definitely won't contain links to your directory-in-question?

Comment: i did use find with type l option. However, i did not eliminate any areas, because that is negating my purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this command, replace targetdir by the directory your are looking for:

```
TARGET=targetdir; find . -type l -exec ls -l {} \; | grep -- "-> $TARGET";
```

Comment: This is the right answer. The accepted answer finds all links, this one finds the ones you're looking for. But I'd replace the CWD find location (`.`) with the root directory and use sudo so you can find more links.